# Register custom AuthenticationProvider in reactive programming model

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm trying to register my own `AuthenticationProvider`.

My config:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  fun customAuthenticationProvider(): CustomAuthenticationProvider {
    return CustomAuthenticationProvider()
  }

  @Bean
  fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    return http.authorizeExchange()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and().build()
  }
}
```

But since I use webflux I cannot use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

What is correct way to enable such `AuthenticationProvider`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've got the answer - I need to register Bean of type `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`. Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5565

Comment: Thanks for sharing this question, would also like to know how did you register any userdetailsservice with the reactiveAuthenticationManager?

Comment: Good stuff! Trying to find the same thing.