# Using more than one JWT Decoder with Spring Webflux Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I read [this post](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/how-to-support-different-jwts-in-your-spring-boot-application/) about using multiple JWT Decoders in Spring Security flow which seems easy, except that I'm using **Spring Webflux** and not **Spring WebMVC** , which has the convenient `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that you can extend to add multiple `AuthenticationProvider` instances. With Webflux you no longer extend some class to configure security.

So what's the problem while trying to replicate this with Webflux? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502945/register-custom-authenticationprovider-in-reactive-programming-model/51597921) . As you can read there Webflux doesn't use `AuthenticationProvider` , you have to declare a `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` instead. The problem is I don't know how to make Spring use multiple authentication managers, each of them using its own `ReactiveJwtDecoder`.

My first authentication manager would be the one spring creates automatically using this property:

```yaml
      security:
        oauth2:
          resourceserver:
            jwt:
              issuer-uri: ${scacap.auth0.issuer}
```

And my second Authentication Manager would be a custom one I'm declaring in my Security `@Configuration`:

```kotlin
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(JwkProperties::class)
    internal class SecurityConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        fun securityFilter(
            http: ServerHttpSecurity,
            scalableAuthenticationManager: JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager
        ): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    
            http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(Auth0AuthenticationConverter())
    
            return http.build()
        }
    
        @Bean
        fun customAuthenticationManager(jwkProperties: JwkProperties): JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager {
            val decoder = NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.withJwkSource { Flux.fromIterable(jwkProperties.jwkSet.keys) }.build()
            return JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(decoder).also {
                it.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(ScalableAuthenticationConverter())
            }
        }
    }
```

I am debugging and it seems only one authentication manager is being picked so only [auth0](https://auth0.com/) tokens can be validated, but I also want to validate tokens with my own [JWKS](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets#:%7E:text=The%20JSON%20Web%20Key%20Set,signing%20JWTs%3A%20RS256%20and%20HS256.)

Comment: Either you specify all configuration in the properties, or you override in a custom HttpSecurity configuration. You cant specify things in the properties (which uses springs autoconfiguration) and then create a full custom configuration and expect both to work.

Comment: @Toerktumlare true. After reading your comment I concentrated on making it work with two manually instantiated decoders. If you're curious on how I did it you can see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is what I ended up doing:

Instead of trying someway to pass several `AuthenticationManager`s to Spring Security flow, I created one wrapper which I call `DualAuthenticationManager`. This way for Spring there is only one manager and I do the orchestration inside my wrapper like `firstManager.authenticate(auth).onErrorResume { secondManager.authenticate(auth) }`.

It ended up being shorter than I thought it would be. It's all in a `@Bean` function in my security `@Configuration` . And each manager has it's own converter function so I can create my `UserToken` model with two different JWTs :)

```kotlin
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(*[JwtProperties::class, Auth0Properties::class])
    internal class SecurityConfiguration(
        private val jwtProperties: JwtProperties,
        private val auth0Properties: Auth0Properties
    ) {
    
        @Bean
        fun securityFilter(
            http: ServerHttpSecurity,
            dualAuthManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager
        ): SecurityWebFilterChain {
            http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority(Authorities.USER)
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
                .authenticationManager(dualAuthManager)
    
            return http.build()
        }
    
        @Bean
        fun dualAuthManager(): ReactiveAuthenticationManager {
            val firstManager = fromOidcIssuerLocation(auth0Properties.issuer).let { decoder ->
                JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(decoder).also {
                    it.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(FirstAuthenticationConverter())
                }
            }
    
            val secondManager = withJwkSource { fromIterable(jwtProperties.jwkSet.keys) }.build().let { decoder ->
                JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(decoder).also {
                    it.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(SecondAuthenticationConverter())
                }
            }
    
            return ReactiveAuthenticationManager { auth ->
                firstManager.authenticate(auth).onErrorResume { secondManager.authenticate(auth) }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how my converters look:

```kotlin
    class FirstAuthenticationConverter : Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> {
    
        override fun convert(jwt: Jwt): Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
            val authorities = jwt.getClaimAsStringList(AUTHORITIES) ?: emptyList()
            val userId = jwt.getClaimAsString(PERSON_ID)
            val email = jwt.getClaimAsString(EMAIL)
    
            return Mono.just(
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    UserToken(jwt.tokenValue, UserTokenType.FIRST, userId, email),
                    null,
                    authorities.map { SimpleGrantedAuthority(it) }
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

Then in my controller I get the object I built in the converter by doing:

```kotlin
@AuthenticationPrincipal userToken: UserToken
```